# Qt 5.6.3 does not choose correctly rendering mode

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qml

I've deploy desktop application that using QML.
According to Qt [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html#dynamically-loading-graphics-drivers), Qt automatically choose most relevant rendering mode. 
When I work from the Qt Creator, Qt runs correct mode (I've check it using Fraps and LogView).
But if I run application from the folder (with dll binaries), app using Software rendering. If I delete **opengl32.dll** - app using native OpenGL mode.

Comparing results are below.

Run from the Creator:

> qt.qpa.gl: Basic wglCreateContext gives version 4.6    qt.qpa.gl:
>   OpenGL 2.0 entry points available  qt.qpa.gl: GPU features: QSet()
>   qt.qpa.gl: supportedRenderers GpuDescription(vendorId=0x10de,
>   deviceId=0x1201, subSysId=0x0, revision=161, driver: "nvd3dum.dll",
>   version=23.21.13.8843, "NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560") renderer: 
>   QFlags(0x1|0x2|0x4|0x8|0x20)   qt.qpa.gl: Qt: Using WGL and OpenGL from
>   "opengl32.dll"     qt.qpa.gl: create OpenGL: "NVIDIA
>   Corporation","GeForce GTX 560/PCIe/SSE2" default ContextFormat: v4.6
>   profile: 0 options: QFlags(0x4),SampleBuffers, Extension-API present
>   Extensions: 326

Run from the folder:

> qt.qpa.gl: Basic wglCreateContext gives version 3.0    qt.qpa.gl: OpenGL
>   2.0 entry points available     qt.qpa.gl: GPU features: QSet()     qt.qpa.gl: supportedRenderers GpuDescription(vendorId=0x10de,
>   deviceId=0x1201, subSysId=0x0, revision=161, driver: "nvd3dum.dll",
>   version=23.21.13.8843, "NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560") renderer: 
>   QFlags(0x1|0x2|0x4|0x8|0x20)   qt.qpa.gl: Qt: Using WGL and OpenGL from
>   "opengl32.dll"     qt.qpa.gl: create OpenGL: "VMware, Inc.","Gallium 0.4
>   on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 128 bits)" default ContextFormat: v3.0 profile:
>   0 options: QFlags(0x4),SampleBuffers, Extension-API present
>   Extensions: 184

Comment: Why would you have a local copy of  opengl32.dll in some application folder? This is not how it is supposed to work.

Comment: @derhass yes, that's was a problem! I've get this one by the advice from https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-34964
Not so good one advice :)